# How to update progress bar while making a Django Rest api request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My django rest app accepts request to scrape multiple pages for prices & compare them (which takes time ~5 seconds) then returns a list of the prices from each page as a json object.
I want to update the user with the current operation, for example if I scrape 3 pages I want to update the interface like this :
Searching 1/3
Searching 2/3
Searching 3/3
How can I do this? 
I am using Angular 2 for my front end but this shouldn't make a big difference as it's a backend issue.

Comment: Are you keeping track of page count using any flag in the backend? And also edit your question to add the models and views which you are using. This will help one to debug better.

Comment: My backend loops through a list of urls & gets prices. I will add the model asap

Answer (score 10):

This isn't the only way, but this is how I do this in Django.

---

## Things you'll need

#### Asynchronous worker procecess

This allows you to do work outside the context of the request-response cycle. The most common are either [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) or [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery). I'd recommend django-rq for its simplicity, especially if all you're implementing is a progress indicator.

#### Caching layer (optional)

While you can use the database for persistence in this case, temporary cache key-value stores make more sense here as the progress information is ephemeral. The Memcached backend is built into Django, however I'd recommend switching to [Redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis) as it's more fully featured, super fast, and since it's behind Django's caching abstraction, does not add complexity. (It's also a requirement for using the django-rq worker processes above)

---

## Implementation

#### Overview

Basically, we're going to send a request to the server to start the async worker, and poll a different progress-indicator endpoint which gives the current status of that worker's progress until it's finished (or failed).

#### Server side

1. Refactor the function you'd like to track the progress of into an async task function (using the `@job` decorator in the case of django-rq)
2. The initial `POST` endpoint should first generate a random unique ID to identify the request (possibly with `uuid`). Then, pass the POST data along with this unique ID to the async function (in django-rq this would look something like `function_name.delay(payload, unique_id)`). Since this is an async call, the interpreter does not wait for the task to finish and moves on immediately. Return a HttpResponse with a JSON payload that includes the unique ID.
3. Back in the async function, we need to set the progress using cache. At the very top of the function, we should add a `cache.set(unique_id, 0)` to show that there is zero progress so far. Using your own math implementation, as the progress approaches 100% completion, change this value to be closer to `1`. If for some reason the operation fails, you can set this to `-1`.
4. Create a new endpoint to be polled by the browser to check the progress. This looks for a `unique_id` query parameter and uses this to look up the progress with `cache.get(unique_id)`. Return a JSON object back with the progress amount.

#### Client side

1. After sending the POST request for the action and receiving a response, that response should include the `unique_id`. Immediately start polling the progress endpoint at a regular interval, setting the `unique_id` as a query parameter. The interval could be something like 1 second using `setInterval()`, with logic to prevent sending a new request if there is still a pending request.
2. When the progress received equals to `1` (or `-1` for failures), you know the process is finished and you can stop polling

---

That's it! It's a bit of work just to get progress indicators, but once you've done it once it's much easier to re-use the pattern in other projects.

Another way to do this which I have not explored is via Webhooks / [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). In this way, polling is not required, and the server simply sends the messages to the client directly.